# Get Eigensystem to return orthogonal eigenvectors for Hermitian matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I have a Hermitian matrix, and I would like to get a list of orthogonal eigenvectors and corresponding eigenvalues. But when there are degenerate eigenvalues, sometimes Eigensystem/Eigenvectors returns eigenvectors that are not orthogonal.

Now I could fix this by hunting down every eigenspace, and getting an orthogonal basis for it, but I feel like there must be a more efficient and less messy way.

Example:

```
eVectors =  Eigenvectors[{{1,-2,0,-2,0,0},{-2,1,0,-2,0,0},{0,0,1,0,-2,-2},
{-2,-2,0,1,0,0},{0,0,-2,0,1,-2},{0,0,-2,0,-2,1}}];
```

Now to find out whether they are orthogonal:

```
eVectors.ConjugateTranspose[eVectors]
```

which returns some nonzero off-diagonal elements.

Comment: According to the Documentation Center page for `Eigenvectors`, "For approximate numerical matrices m, the eigenvectors are normalized." and "For exact or symbolic matrices m, the eigenvectors are not normalized.". Thus to fix this, apply `N` to your matrix, and the result will be orthonormal, as you desired.

Comment: The reason for this behavior is simple: for exact input, the resulting eigenvectors can be complex numeric expressions, and calculating norms and other such arithmetic used in the Gram-Schmidt procedure becomes frightening from a computation-time perspective. As a result, Mathematica does not normalize symbolic eigenvectors because doing so could be catastrophic. In contrast, with floating-point results, such performance considerations do not apply, and so by default it orthonormalizes them.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus Could you post it as an answer? *Normalization* and *orthogonalization* are different procedures so I don't think it is RTFM. May be a duplicate, but I can't find such Q&A.

Comment: That's useful @DumpsterDoofus, thanks. I would like to be able to do this exactly in some cases, with a (real) parameter or two in the matrix, so I'm still interested in how best to go about it efficiently.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus I agree with  ybeltukov, you should post that as an answer. Not only because it seems right but also because it shows a good way to reason about the inner workings of a black box.

Comment: @ybeltukov: Yes, I mistakenly read "normalized" as "orthonormalized", so I'll retract my close-vote. I'm still not sure of a good way to go about this if the OP wants exact results, though. Any thoughts?

Comment: This is an old post and old problem. Part of the issue is that orthogonality is guaranteed between eigenvectors with different eigenvalues for a symmetric matrix. However, for multiple linearly independent eigenvectors with the SAME eigenvalue (degenerate case), any linear combination of these eigenvectors is also shares the same eigenvalue of that symmetric matrix. It forms a subspace. A number of friendly diagonalization routines will give you a good orthgonal subset for the 'degenerate' case.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

While the documentation does not specifically say that symbolic Hermitian matrices are not necessarily given orthonormal eigenbases, it does say

> For approximate numerical matrices m, the eigenvectors are normalized.
>
> For exact or symbolic matrices m, the eigenvectors are not normalized.

From this, it's reasonable to guess that if Mathematica isn't smart enough to normalize symbolic results, then it's also probably not smart enough to *ortho*normalize them, either.

Why is Mathematica not smart enough to do this? For exact input, the resulting eigenvectors can be complex numeric expressions, and calculating norms and other such arithmetic used in the Gram-Schmidt procedure becomes frightening from a computation-time perspective. As a result, Mathematica does not normalize symbolic eigenvectors because doing so could be catastrophic.

In contrast, with floating-point results, such performance considerations do not apply, and so by default it orthonormalizes them. Thus, if numeric results are acceptable, you can simply apply `N` to your array, and the results will automatically be orthonormal.

Otherwise, if numeric results are not acceptable, then you will have to manually orthogonalize the individual subspaces. Here is one method:

```
A = {{1, -2, 0, -2, 0, 0}, {-2, 1, 0, -2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 
    0, -2, -2}, {-2, -2, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -2, 0, 1, -2}, {0, 0, -2,
     0, -2, 1}};
{val, vec} = Eigensystem[A];
o = Flatten[Orthogonalize /@ FindClusters[N@val -> vec], 1];
```

It is orthonormal, and it diagonalizes `A`:

```
o.o\[Transpose] == IdentityMatrix[6]
Simplify[o.A.o\[Transpose]] == DiagonalMatrix[val]
(*True*)
(*True*)
```

While it works for your example matrix, it may fail for more complicated cases, so check your results.

As a further example of the catastrophic issues involved with orthogonalizing symbolic vectors, try executing the following:

```
Orthogonalize[Eigenvectors[#.#\[Transpose] &@RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {6, 6}]]]
```

The calculation just goes on and on, because the eigenvectors are comprised of giant `Root` objects. So if symbolic results are what you need, you may run into trouble.

Comment: "it's reasonable to guess that if Mathematica isn't smart enough to normalize symbolic results, then it's also probably not smart enough..."?? I beg to differ. In point of fact, Mathematica is smart enough to NOT normalize those results. It would be a bad idea. Orthonormalizing them would compound the badness considerably.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Yup, that was the main point of my answer (ie, that orthonormalizing symbolic results would be a disaster). I thought I made this point clear in the sentences that came afterwards, but maybe I should reword it?

Comment: Your comment is sufficient, I think. (If someone sees mine, they'll see yours. And if neither is seen, it's not an issue.)

Answer (score 6):

Here is a method that works when eigenvalues do not involve `Root` objects. Perturb symmetrically, and in such a way that equal eigenvalues become unequal (or enough do that we can get an orthogonal set of eigenvectors). Then take the limit as the perturbation goes to zero.

Here I add `e` to the (1,3) and (3,1) positions.

```
pmat = {{1, -2, e, -2, 0, 0}, {-2, 1, 0, -2, 0, 0}, {e, 0, 1, 0, -2, -2},
  {-2, -2, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -2, 0, 1, -2}, {0, 0, -2, 0, -2, 1}};

{pvals, pvecs} = Eigensystem[pmat];
vecs = Limit[pvecs, e -> 0]

(* Out[3691]= {{0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1}, {0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {-1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1},
  {2, -1, -2, -1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {-2, 1, -2, 1, 1, 1}} *)
```

Check orthogonality:

```
In[3692]:= vecs.Transpose[vecs]

(* Out[3692]= {{2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0},
  {0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12}} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason that that the orthogonalization fails is not because there is any problem performing Graham Schmidt. It is because no general symbolic solutions to polynomials beyond 5th order are known and computing eigenvalues of a 5x5 matrix is equivalent to solving a 5th order polynomial. (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polynomial.html ) .

The original problem had trouble getting orthogonal symbolic eigenvectors for the matrix

```
M = {{1, -2, 0, -2, 0, 0}, {-2, 1, 0, -2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, -2, -2}, {-2, -2, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -2, 0, 1, -2}, {0, 0, -2, 0, -2, 1}}
```

In spite of the fact that this is a 6x6 matrix, it's eigenvalues can be computed exactly and they are plus and minus 3.

```
 ev=Eigenvalues[M]
```

with that knowledge in hand it is trivial to compute an orthogonal basis for the degenerate eigenvalues. First note that that a basis can be computed by asking for the null space of 
M-lambda I for each lambda in the spectrum of M. In the case at hand the following two sets of eigenvectors span the two subspaces. The eigenvectors in one set are orthogonal to those in the other set, as they must be.

```
 evp = NullSpace[(M - 3 IdentityMatrix[6])]
 evm = NullSpace[(M + 3 IdentityMatrix[6])]

evp[[1]].evm[[1]]
```

Orthogonalization of the degenerate subspaces proceeds without difficulty as can be seen from the following.

```
orthogplus=Orthogonalize[evp]
orthogminux=Orthogonalize[evm]
```

all work quite cleanly.

If you can get the exact eigenvalues you will be able to obtain the exact eigenvectors and you'll be able to orthogonalize those that correspond to degenerate eigenvalues without difficulty. A general procedure for obtaining a symbolic orthogonal basis for any matrix M is:

```
M = {{1, -2, 0, -2, 0, 0}, {-2, 1, 0, -2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 
0, -2, -2}, {-2, -2, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -2, 0, 1, -2}, {0, 0, -2,
 0, -2, 1}};

{evals,evecs}=Eigensystem[M];
```

If the spectrum (evals) is not exact, STOP. There is no symbolic eigenbasis because it is not possible to compute the eigenvalues symbolically.  I don't know how to tell Mathematica to tell  if a spectrum is exact or not but it will be apparent by inspection. If the eigenvalues are exact they will either be rational or will involve symbolic expressions containing radicals.

```
orthogaleigenvectors=Orthogonalize[evecs];
```

Comment: Umm, I don't see what might be the impediment for 5x5 and beyond. The eigenvectors might be expressed in terms of `Root` objects. But that won't stop one from using Gram-Schmidt. It might make it quite slow perhaps, but that's a computational complexity issue and not a mathematical obstruction per se.

Comment: There is a fundamental difference between the solutions to a 4th order and lower polynomials and 5th order and higher. The solution to 4th order and lower polynomials can be calculated using the operations of root extraction, addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division. It was proven by Abel in the early 19th century that 5th order and higher equations have no symbolic solution in terms of those operations. Later Hermite and others found solutions to the 5th and higher order polynomials in terms of special functions but as far as I know Mathematica cannot implement those solutions.

Comment: The current version of Mathematica will never return the symbolic solution to the general 5th order (and higher) equations no matter how long you wait.

Comment: Ummm. Are you claiming that there is no difference between what Mathematica returns for this:

    Solve[a x^4 + b x^3 + c x^2 + d x + e == 0, x]

and for this:

    Solve[aa x^5 + a x^4 + b x^3 + c x^2 + d x + e == 0, x]?

Why is the 5th order in terms of root objects and the 4th order is explicit?

Comment: No. I'm claiming that Gram-Schmidt will work regardless of whether fed vectors comprised of radicals or (as I explicitly noted) `Root` objects. So this is not a case where "orthogonalization fails".

Comment: I guess it depends on what you mean by fails. The following runs  in ~10 seconds. 

M = {{3/2, 5, 4, 8}, {0, 12/2, 11, 2 + 1/6}, {0, 0, 2/2, 2/3}, {0, 0, 
   0, 4/5/2}}
M = Transpose[M] + M;
MatrixForm[M]
cp = CharacteristicPolynomial[M, \[Lambda]]
evals = \[Lambda] /. Solve[cp == 0, \[Lambda]]
evals = Simplify[evals];
evecs = NullSpace[M - # IdentityMatrix[4]] & /@ evals;
evecs = Flatten[evecs, 1];
Simplify[evecs[[1]].evecs[[2]]]
Simplify[evecs[[1]].evecs[[3]]]
Simplify[evecs[[1]].evecs[[4]]]
Simplify[evecs[[2]].evecs[[3]]]
Simplify[evecs[[2]].evecs[[4]]]
Simplify[evecs[[3]].evecs[[4]]]

Comment: If you try the same thing on a generic 5x5 exact matrix it will NEVER finish. To my mind that constitutes failure. It is not a matter of it taking "a long time": it is a matter of it taking forever because Mathematica doesn't know how to solve the general 5th order polynomial.

Comment: No, it's slow-to-forever because of intermediate swell. This is going to happen whether one has `Root` objects or radicals. For example, try `Orthogonalize` on the eigenvectors from a random 4x4 matrix of integers. You will find it to be slow with either setting of `Quartics` e.g. `{vals, vecs} = Eigensystem[mat, Quartics -> True]; Timing[v2 = Orthogonalize[vecs];]` (were `True` to work much better, it would be the default setting.) This has little to do with the form of the root solutions per se. It has to do with the computational complexity in the algebraic manipulations thereof.

Comment: Here is an example. Note the case of radicals is the slow one. There may be ways to improve on that but I'd say go with `Root` objects from the beginning. `SeedRandom[1111];
n = 4;
mat = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {n, n}];
{vals, vecs} = Eigensystem[mat, Cubics -> False, Quartics -> False];
Timing[orthovecs = Orthogonalize[vecs];] (* 20 sec *)
{vals2, vecs2} =
   Eigensystem[mat, Cubics -> True, Quartics -> True];
Timing[orthovecs2 = Orthogonalize[vecs2];] (* much longer*)`

Comment: Root objects are implicit not explicit functions of the parameters. Up to 4th order polynomials a root object is just shorthand for a set of explicit functions which Mathematica can return if forced to. Your problem runs in about 15 seconds on my laptop without root objects if you pose it correctly. 
n = 4;
mat = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {n, n}];
mat = mat + Transpose[mat];
mat = mat/2;
Timing[
 cp = CharacteristicPolynomial[mat, \[Lambda]];
 evals = \[Lambda] /. Simplify[Solve[cp == 0, \[Lambda]]];
 evecs = NullSpace[mat - # IdentityMatrix[n]] & /@ evals;
 evecs = Flatten[#] & /@ evecs;
 ]

Comment: If you set n=5 it will take forever because Mathematica does not know how to solve the characteristic polynomial for n=5 and higher. For those special (measure zero set of) 5th order polynomials for which there are exact solutions in terms of radicals Mathematica will find them and the orthogonalization will proceed in finite time.

Comment: I think I'm going to defer at this point to your expertise. My own understanding of the underlying math and computation is mostly anecdotal. From working with this stuff day in and out since the Bush 41 years.

Comment: I suppose I should mention that when you start with a Hermitian matrix and the eigenvalues are distinct, orthogonalization is essentially free...

Comment: Also: `SeedRandom[1111];
n = 5;
mat = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {n, n}];
{vals, vecs} = Eigensystem[mat];
Timing[vecs2 = RootReduce[vecs];]
Timing[orthvecs = Orthogonalize[vecs2];](*takes around 25 minutes*)` Okay, dead horse sufficiently beaten, time fora new topic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20847/discussion-between-jep-and-daniel-lichtblau).