# How can I get symbolic orthonormal eigenvectors for 3 by 3 hermitian matrix?

Tags: matrix, symbolic

Using the following syntax, I can obtain the symbolic eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the following Hermitian matrix (a,b,c,d are all real parameters):

```
M3:={{a,b,0},{b,c,b},{0,b,d}}
Eigenvalues[M3,Cubics->True]
Eigenvectors[M3,Cubics->True]
```

I have computed the dot product of each of the eigenvectors with each other eigenvector to ensure that they are indeed orthogonal.

However, Mathematica does not normalize them, and when I use Orthogonalize, I get no result (I allowed it to run for five days before I killed the job).

Normalizing is not hard, at least in principle, but the algebra involved will be extensive.  Even if I do the normalization by hand, I'd like to be able to check it against something.  Is it possible to get a set of normalized symbolic eigenvectors?

Answer (score 2):

So you get your eigenvalues and eigenvectors easily enough,

```
M3 := {{a, b, 0}, {b, c, b}, {0, b, d}}
{vals, vecs} = Eigensystem[M3, Cubics -> True];
```

the results are long (but don't have any `Root` objects), and are pasted [here](http://pastebin.com/raw/SrC9sbn8).  As you noticed, the results are orthogonal but not normalized.  I like to check this by substituting random numbers for the variables and taking all the inner products,

```
Dot @@@ 
  Tuples[vecs /. Thread[{a, b, c, d} -> RandomReal[10, 4]], 2] // Chop
(* {20.3231, 0, 0, 0, 2.37878, 0, 0, 0, 1.88533} *)
```

See the informative discussion [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72954/9490) for why this is desired behavior.  But this is a 3x3 matrix, so it is definitely within reason to normalize these symbolic vectors.  You can use the `Normalize` function, but you get the same result if you just do it explicitly,

```
nvecs = #/Sqrt[#.#] & /@ vecs;
```

The resulting vectors are pasted [here](http://pastebin.com/raw/BDXrWUpg).  You can test the orthonormality of the resulting vectors as well,

```
Dot @@@ 
  Tuples[nvecs /. Thread[{a, b, c, d} -> RandomReal[10, 4]], 2] // Chop
(* {1., 0, 0, 0, 1., 0, 0, 0, 1.} *)
```

Comment: A better orthonormality check would be to use `FullSimplify[ConjugateTranspose[nvecs].nvecs == IdentityMatrix[Length[nvecs]]]`. `#/Sqrt[#.#] &` can indeed be used for *symmetric* matrices, but for Hermitian matrices, `Normalize[]` would be more appropriate.